# How do you insert data onto the next free row in a tkinter Treeview (which is linked with an SQLite3 database)?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, sql-insert

The code I have produced so far successfully adds the data into the database and the Treeview. However, it inserts it into the last row.

This is the code I have produced so far:

```
#add a new record to database 
def add_record():
    #Grab record number
    selected = my_tree.focus()
    #Update record 
    my_tree.item(selected, text = '', values=(FL_entry.get(),SL_entry.get(), IDL_entry.get(), CRL_entry.get(),RPL_entry.get(),IPL_entry.get(),))

    #update database 
    #Create a database or connect to one that already exists. 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('RankingsPractice.db')

    #create a cursor instance 
    c = conn.cursor()

    #add new record 
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Players VALUES (:first, :last, :id, :CountyRegion, :RankingPoints, :InactivePeriods)", 
    {
        'first' : FL_entry.get(),
        'last' : SL_entry.get(), 
        'id' : IDL_entry.get(),
        'CountyRegion' : CRL_entry.get(),
        'RankingPoints' : RPL_entry.get(), 
        'InactivePeriods' : IPL_entry.get()  
    })

    
    #commit changes 
    conn.commit()

    #close our connection 
    conn.close()`
```

This adds the data to the treeview and database but does not add it to the next free row unless the user clicks that row first.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You do not insert the record at the end of the treeview, but update the selected row instead.  You should use `my_tree.insert('', 'end', values=...)` instead of `my_tree.item(...)`.

Comment: I have amended the code to what you suggested but it still inserts the data into the last row on the treeview.

Comment: State clear where do you want the record be inserted in the treeview? What do you mean by *"next free row"* actually?

Comment: By saying the next free row, I mean the following row where there is no data stored.

Comment: For a treeview, it is the end then.